# How to pass parameter to the downstream job but shouldn't trigger the downstream job?

Tags: jenkins

I have two jobs which are pipelined, I want to send the `BUILD_NUMBER` info of upstream job to downstream.

The main point is we shouldn't trigger the downstream project. Triggering of downstream project should be manual.

Whenever I trigger the downstream job it need to get the latest `BUILD_NUMBER` of the upstream.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use environment inject plugin in the second job

As mentioned by @VnoC  in the first job write the buildnumber in the properties file like below

```
echo "last_build_number = ${BUILD_NUMBER}"> ../Common.properties
```

Mention in the inject enviornement variable the same property file path for the secod job (Path is repective to the active workspace so keeping it in a common location)

[image]

Now is the second job you can access the variable like $last_build_number

Comment: Should i execute this script 'echo "last_build_number = ${BUILD_NUMBER}"> ../Common.properties' in the shell or should i enter this " last_build_number = ${BUILD_NUMBER} " in Properties Content column ?

Comment: in shell in the firstjob, this will write in the properties file which we are referencing in the second job  ...the file should look  like last_build_number=112 after you build the firstjob ...and then when you run the second job environment inject plugin will be run against the same property file (as we are referencing the same file ) and you should be able to use the variable

Comment: Just to add one thing you have to write  echo "last_build_number = ${BUILD_NUMBER}"> ../Common.properties    and execute it without echo statement the file will not  have the entry

Comment: how can we create a new properties file, and if we are using the jenkins properties file. What will be the location of that file?

Comment: this is not Jenkins properties this can be anyfile with extensions .properties  go through the documentation of environment inject plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could [set an environment variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/), which will then be read by the next job with `WithEnv(${last_build_number}) {...}`.
That is not ideal since this is listed as an anti-pattern in [Top 10 Best Practices for Jenkins Pipeline Plugin](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-jenkins-pipeline-plugin)

> While you can edit some settings in the env global variable, you should use the `withEnv` syntax instead.
>
> Why? because the env variable is global, changing it directly is discouraged as it changes the environment globally, so the `withEnv` syntax is recommended.

Still, in your case, that could be an acceptable workaround.

```
environment {
        last_build_number = ${BUILD_NUMBER}
}
```

I thought first to write it in a file, but the feature of reading parameters from a file is still pending ([`JENKINS-27413`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413)).

Comment: Can I do this: echo $BUILD_NUMER>BUILD_NUMBER.txt as post build in upstream project and this is stored at upstream workspace. Do i have any chance of copying that file into the downstream project workspace?

Comment: @EjjagiriVenkatesh Not sure, which is why I suggested environment variable instead. But still, you can try in the downstream job to `copy ../name_of_upstream_job/BUILD_NUMBER.txt .`